# Linux file deletion error

Tags: linux, shell

Every time I run this code I get the error File or directory doesn't exist. Why?

```
read -p "Enter the filename/path of the file you wish to delete : " filename
echo "Do you want to delete this file"
echo "Y/N"
read ans
case "$ans" in 
   Y) "`readlink -f $filename`" >>~/TAM/store & mv $filename ~/TAM/dustbin
        echo "File moved" ;;
   N) "File Not deleted" ;;
esac
```

When I enter the file name/directory exactly and triple check its right I still get this error, but the readlink part works.

Comment: i did discover that It does not work as that However /root/TAM/filename works

Comment: are you sure that there is nothing missing from this script? `"..." >> ...` is not a valid construct, unless you are planing to execute the file that you are trying to move...

Comment: BTW, is this some kind of homework? Because, [a quite similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13502483/507519) was posted a few minutes ago...

Comment: @TAM: you might want to have a look at my answer for that other question - at least one of the points I mentioned applies to your case as well...

Comment: @thkala Please don't add the homework tag. It is obsolete and in the process of being removed. See the tag wiki for further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paraphrasing/summarizing/extending [my answer for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13502810/507519):

- I doubt you really meant to use `&` instead of `&&` in your script.
- `"File Not deleted"` is *not* a valid command on any Linux system that I have used. Perhaps you are missing an `echo` there?
- You have to fix your variable quotation. If the `filename` variable contains whitespace, then `$filename` is expanded by the shell into more than one arguments. You need to enclose it into double quotes:

  ```
  mv "$filename" ~/TAM/dustbin
  ```
- I do not see your script creating the `~/TAM/` directory anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `echo` and one `&&`.

1. Use `` echo "`command`" `` to pipe the result string of commands. Alternatively, you may directly use the `command` without backticks and quotes, (not storing the result in a string), in which case you do not need an `echo` because the command will pipe its result to the next command.
2. The single `&` will run the preceding command in the background (async.). To check for return values and conditionally execute you need `&&` and `||`.

Here is a complete solution/example (incl. some more logging):

```
# modified example not messing the $HOME dir.
# should be save to run in a separate dir
touch testfile                 #create file for testing
read -p "Enter the filename/path of the file you wish to delete : " filename
echo "Do you want to delete this file: $filename"
echo "Y/N"
read ans
touch movedfiles               #create a file to store the moved files
[ -d _trash ] || mkdir _trash  #create a dustbin if not already there
case "$ans" in
    Y)  readlink -f "$filename" >> movedfiles && echo "File name stored" &&
        mv "$filename" _trash && echo "File moved" ;;
    N)  echo "File Not deleted" ;;
esac
cat movedfiles                 #display all moved files
```

Comment: It would be simpler to use `readlink -f "$filename" >> ~/TAM/store` (to use the name from the question; you used `movedfiles`).  You don't need the backslash after the `&&`, either; this is not a sea-shell you're programming.

Comment: Thx, I didn't know about the `&&` not requiring the backslash at the end of a line.